# Force .NET to use a Certain IP when Connecting to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, .net

I have a situation, where I have a computer with multiple IP's, the computers primary IP will never change, but all the secondary IP's will.

I connect to a remote MYSQL computer and I have access granted based on my IP address. Sometimes, my PC likes to select one of the secondary IP's.

I looked in to the "Set As Source" flag and tested that solution, but what happens is, that I can't select those extra IP's for outbound communication.

> Dim IPS As IPAddress() = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())

Any IP with the "set as source" = false - won't be returned with the above code.

So how would I get around this dilemma? I can't seem to find a solution, with socket progamming I can bind any IP I want, but I don't see a way to do this with a mySQL connection.

Comment: I think the solution is to whitelist your secondary IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I was able to accomplish this by adding a second NIC on the Server and putting the single IP on 1 NIC and all the other IP's on the second NIC. Then putting in a route that forces the traffic through the Primary NIC interface to MySQL.

Without two NICS, you can't select which IP it uses, But with two you can assign the routes to either NIC (Interface).